# Getting the property / array name of a json object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some json where the description can act as a key of an array of json.

for example:

```
 { 'groups' : array[
                0 => {
                      'id' : '1'
                      'free gifts' : array[
                                       0 => {'id': 1
                                             'gift cards': array[
                                                            {..more json}
                                                           ]
                                            },
                                       1 => { ... more json }
                                        ] 
              ],
              1 => {
                      'id' : '2'
                      'discounts & incentives' : array[
                                       0 => { .. more json },
                                       2 => { ... more json }
                                        ] 
              ]
 }
```

this can go on to any depth, each group or array of json has an id value and a name or description (property name) what I want to is recursively iterate through without knowing the depth and get:

```
(All) groups->id and descriptions so (1 = freegifts, 2 = discounts & incentives
```

and the same for all other levels where the name or description is an array

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: The clue is in the question is it not very clear?

Comment: no, it's not. as we don't know _how_ you iterate we can't give an answer of how to get something from something we don't know.

Comment: the answer could be `->id`. or `['id']`. or `$i`. or `$key`. or `key()`. We just can't know - because the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: The output you want isn't sufficiently defined. If trying to get an array that uses the id as key and description as value, you're going to have trouble because it looks like you have the same ids with different descriptions depending on depth. But it's hard to tell if that actually is what you're trying to get, because the output example isn't written as PHP code.

Comment: I see Jeff - I have tried to json_decode to an associative array then loop through using a foreach $key => $val pair then check if $key is itself an array using the is_array() function and then loop through that but the trouble is 1 I don't know the depth this I suppose I could overcome using a recursive function and 2 I do not know how to access the name of the array which forms its parent i.e "free gifts"

Comment: if you don't know the depth, you need a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I convert the json to an associative array and then use the following recursive function to iterate through each level:

```
$array = json_decode($json);

recursive_key_val_lookup($array);

function recursive_key_val_lookup($array=[])
{
   foreach($array as $key=>$val)
   {
       if(is_array($val))
       {
           echo "$key is array<br>";
           $this->recursive_key_val_lookup($val);
       } else {
           echo "$key => $val";
       }
   }
}
```